# Present Tense and Passive Voice = Is + V1

Tags: passive-voice, present-simple

Is there is meaning difference if use *Is + V1 & Is + V2*?

a) This is the room which is share by 5 student.

(Referring to the Present tense fact that 5 student are sharing this room)

b) This is the room which is shared by 5 student.

(Referring as Present passive Passive voice mean room is shared by 5 student)

Help me to understand the difference.

Comment: Just to note, native speakers don't generally number the forms of verbs. You can call them by names, or use the examples. This was an understandable question because the examples told us what you meant by the numbered forms.

Comment: This numbering system is widely used to teach students english in some countries. v1 indicating present form, v2 past and v3 past perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Neither sentence is grammatical. You must use the plural, “students,” when talking about any number of them besides one. And “that” is preferred to “which” in this context. “Share” certainly does not work. You must use the past participle “shared” in this context. If you wanted to change the tense of the sentence, you would change the verb *is* (the one that precedes “shared”):

Past:

> This is the room that was shared by five students.

Present:

> This is the room that is shared by five students.

Future:

> This is the room that will be shared by five students.

Comment: would *This is the room that is being shared by five students* work as well?

Comment: Sure, that would work for the present also - similar meaning to “is shared”.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the room which is share by 5 students.

This is grammatically incorrect.

> This is the room which is shared by 5 students.

This one is correct, moreover, here **shared** is not the past form of **share**, shared is past participle here.